# deploy issue on ckan 2.0 over apache2

Tags: apache, installation, ckan

I have the following problem after try to deploy ckan 2.0 over apache2. 
here is the log from apache:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/demo.ckan.net.error.log
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return context.create()
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/ubuntu-ckan-last/pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.object_type.invoke(self)
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/ubuntu-ckan-last/pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/ubuntu-ckan-last/pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     val = callable(*args, **kw)
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/ubuntu-ckan-last/pyenv/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 104, in make_app
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     who_parser.parse(open(app_conf['who.config_file']))
[Tue Apr 02 10:34:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] KeyError: 'who.config_file'
```

i followed the latest documentation on how to deploy a ckan 2.1a instance over apache or nginx...

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests it cannot find the `who.config_file` bit of your CKAN config file (e.g. std.ini):

```
 [app:main]
 ...
 who.config_file = %(here)s/who.ini
```

However this is the first point in the code which accesses this config file, so it suggests the something more fundamental is up with the config file.

Check your wsgi script file contains the correct path to your config file. The line looks like this:

```
config_file = '/usr/local/demo.ckan.net/pyenv/src/ckan/development.ini'
```